# vertically-center floated blocks using css without using tables or absolute positioning

Tags: css, html

I am trying to vertically center all the images in my header.

http://jsfiddle.net/falven/qbcswo0g/1/

```
<header>
    <div class="centered">
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href=""><img src="http://dapper-apps.com/media/nav/ATFrancoNav.png" alt="AT Franco"></a></li>
                <li><a href=""><img src="http://dapper-apps.com/media/nav/KamisNightmareNav.png" alt="Kami's Nightmare"></a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <h1><a href="/"><img src="http://dapper-apps.com/media/Logo.svg" alt="Dapper Apps"></a></h1>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href=""><img src="" alt="Spotter"></a></li>
                <li><a href=""><img src="http://dapper-apps.com/media/nav/DapperAppsNav.png" alt="About"></a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</header>

.centered {
    margin: 0 10% 0 10%;
}

header {
    background-color: #FFF;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 2;
    position: fixed;
    transition: all 0.15s linear;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #D6D6D6;
}

header > div {
    overflow: hidden;
}

header > div > h1 {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
}

header > div > h1 > a > img {
    width: 100%;
}

header > div > nav {
    width: 25%;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
}

header > div > nav > ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

header > div > nav > ul > li {
    display: inline;
    width: 50%;
}

header > div > nav > ul > li > a > img {
    width: 25%;
    max-width: 50px;
}
```

All of the answers I have found involve using semantically-incorrect table layouts and absolute positioning which would not work in my case because the header is fixed. What I would like in essence, is to be able to keep adding list items to the navigation links in my header and have the header grow vertically automatically as it does, but keep the `nav` and `h1` elements centered vertically and occupying the entire height of the header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use inline block with vertical align property. Make sure to remove the float properties from nav and h1.

http://jsfiddle.net/qbcswo0g/3/

```
header > div {
    font-size: 0; /* fix for white space */
}

header > div > nav, header > div > h1 {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

Comment: What is the uhm white-space problem that your css fixes?

Comment: @FranciscoAguilera there is an excellent article for explaining it  - https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Answer (score 0):

With flexbox this is very easy.

Just add `display: flex;` and `align-items: center;` to the parent of the elements which contain the images. (here it's the div with class centered)

```
.centered {
    margin: 0 10% 0 10%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center; /* align vertical */
}
```

### [Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/qbcswo0g/2/)

There are actually a number of ways to achieve vertical centering, take a look at this [CSS-tricks article](https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/) which guides you through the various ways to do this according to your specific situation.

Comment: Thanks, but flexbox is only available in 60% of the market atm.